# Strange url's generated - i18n_routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Use rails 3.2, i18n, i18n_routing.

An example of my url's

```
domain/nl/vakantiehuizen/house-property-name
domain/nl/vakantiehuizen/house-property-name/reviews
domain/en/ferienwohnung/house-property-name
domain/en/ferienwohnung/house-property-name
```

controller names (vakantiehuizen, ferienwohnung) are translated by the locales (de.yml, en.yml). The name of the controller is this example is houses controller/model

Just a week ago i get warning messages google webmastertools! with this url's

```
nltarget/houses/le-carpine/
nltarget/houses/le-carpine/reviews
```

500 responses because this page doesn't exist.

What is wrong here? bad/slow server response?

part of logfile:

```
 House::Translation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 17 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1
  House::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 20 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1
  House::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 24 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1
  House::Translation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 13 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1
  House::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 2 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1
  House::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 4 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1
  House::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 25 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1

  House::Translation Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 19 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1
  Appartment::Translation Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `appartment_translations`.* FROM `appartment_translations` WHERE `appartment_translations`.`appartment_id` = 22 AND `appartment_translations`.`locale` = 'nltarget' LIMIT 1
```

i have seen that locale parameter is set to "nltarget" and not "nl"

Mostly the locale params is set correct like this:

```
 House::Translation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `house_translations`.* FROM `house_translations` WHERE `house_translations`.`house_id` = 13 AND `house_translations`.`locale` = 'nl' LIMIT 1
  Amenity::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `amenity_translations`.* FROM `amenity_translations` WHERE `amenity_translations`.`amenity_id` = 13 AND `amenity_translations`.`locale` = 'nl' LIMIT 1
  Review::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `review_translations`.* FROM `review_translations` WHERE `review_translations`.`review_id` IS NULL AND `review_translations`.`locale` = 'nl' LIMIT 1
  Amenity::Translation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `amenity_translations`.* FROM `amenity_translations` WHERE `amenity_translations`.`amenity_id` = 13 AND `amenity_translations`.`locale` = 'nl' LIMIT 1
```

How is it possibly that locale "nl" is set to "nltarget"?

Comment: We need more information. Controller code, routes, full log message, etc.

Comment: just updated my question with more info

Comment: Try and search the full project for word target. Maybe you have it somewhere and doing wrong concatenation. Just an idea